# JOOQ - column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jooq

I'm having an issue related to JOOQ.

**---------**
This is my "setup" that led to the issue.
Table:

```
CREATE TABLE "public".xyz
(
  id UUID NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_t_xyz PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Generated field with JOOQ is correct

```
public final TableField<XYZRecord, UUID> ID = createField("id", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.UUID.nullable(false), this, "comment");
```

UUID is from `java.util.*`

My "custom" POJO with UUID from `java.util.*`:

```
public class XYZ {

    @NotNull
    private UUID id;

    public XYZ (@NotNull UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

DSL configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public DefaultDSLContext dsl() {
        return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration());
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() {
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider
            (new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource));
    }

    public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
        DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();
        jooqConfiguration.set(connectionProvider());
        jooqConfiguration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(exceptionTransformer()));
        return jooqConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public ExceptionTranslator exceptionTransformer() {
        return new ExceptionTranslator();
    }
}
```

Datasource in application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xyz-data
```

Version of jooq is 3.10.5. I'm using `spring-boot-starter-jooq` with spring boot in version `2.0.0.RELEASE`. PostgresSQL version is 10.
**------------------**
When I try to insert data like this:

```
    dslContext.insertInto(XYZ, XYZ.ID)
        .values(xyz.getId()).execute();
```

It does not work for some reason. As I understand from exception below JOOQ is casting UUID to string and therefore the SQL is invalid. Should I write some kind of converter or did I define something in wrong way?

Error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Access database using jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [insert into "public"."xyz" ("id") values (?)]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 225
[...]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 225
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2422)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2167)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:144)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:209)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:429)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.execute(AbstractDMLQuery.java:452)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:347)
    ... 51 more
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this exact issue with Spring Boot. I could work around the issue by explicitly specifying the Postgres Dialect when setting up the DefaultConfiguration object.

E.g. in your DSL configuration:

```
public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
    DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();

    // Explicitly set the Dialect
    jooqConfiguration.setSQLDialect(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);

    jooqConfiguration.set(connectionProvider());
    jooqConfiguration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(exceptionTransformer()));
    return jooqConfiguration;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you. Adding SQL dialect helped in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in jOOQ: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7351

It seems to happen only when binding `null` values as UUIDs. The workaround is to implement your own data type binding:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case it is also happening when the UUID is not null (e.g generated with UUID.randomUUID();). About converter - what should I convert? java.util.UUID into java.util.UUID?

Comment: Interesting - perhaps this was more broken in 3.10 than in 3.11, where the fix has been applied thus far. I meant to implement your own data type binding (`Binding`), not a `Converter`. You'll need to support UUID on a JDBC level. I'll be happy to answer specific questions in a new question here on Stack Overflow.